# Passing a href link into Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have about 8 pages with various multiple sections i.e. 101, 102 etc.

```
<div id="accordion" class="expandme">
   <h4>101 Header</h4>
   <div><p>Text Text Text.</p>
      <p>Cross Reference: <a href="#tab102">102</a> 103 104 105 401 501</p>
   </div>

   <div id="#tab102"></div>
      <h4>102 Header</h4>
      <div><p>Text Text Text Text</p>
      <p>Cross Reference: 101 103 104 105 401 501</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

These are accordion expanders for each section. In the cross reference section when someone clicks 102 from the 101 section, it should decollapse the 101 section and expand 102 etc. I know I can do this by hardcoding the ids and a few various other ways but I have a lot of pages and elements and need a more efficient way of using a generic script.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4eysxowy/1/

Comment: Why not just use JQuery UI's [accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/) ?

Comment: Try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/4eysxowy/3/

Comment: Thanks @DaniP I was able to use that and modify it to what I need.